# boost serialize polymorphic class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism, abstract

With the following example I attempting to learn a few new to me concepts.

1. abstraction
2. polymorphic classes
3. factory programming.
4. boost serialization

The nuances of how pointers behave are still something I am working to figure out.

Here is a small program that I have written to show you the issue I am struggling to understand.
When I unserialize the polymorphic object below I only get an object created from the default constructor.
TodoFactory::retrieveATodo is not recreating the object from the serialized data.  This is displayed by the output of "unserialzed command" in that function.

Here is the full program:

```
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

//abstract class
class aTodo{
private:

   friend class boost::serialization::access;

protected:
   const char _initType;

public:
   aTodo():_initType(0x00){};

   aTodo(const char type):_initType(type){};

std::string  oarchive(){
   std::ostringstream archive_stream;
   {
   boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
   archive << *this;
   }

   archive_stream.flush();
   std::string outbound_data=archive_stream.str();

   std::string  foutbound_data;
   foutbound_data=_initType;
   foutbound_data+=outbound_data;
   std::cout << "length: " << foutbound_data.length() << std::endl;
   return foutbound_data;
}


   virtual void Do()=0;
   virtual ~aTodo(){};

   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive & ar, unsigned int version){
      ar & _initType;
   };
   char getInitType(){return _initType;};
};

// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
class todoExec:public aTodo{
private:
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(
            Archive& ar,
            unsigned int version
            )
    {
      std::cout << "serialize todoexec" << std::endl;
    //base
    boost::serialization::base_object<aTodo>(*this);
//derived
        ar & _command;
    }

  std::string _command;
protected:

public:
   static const char _TYPE=0x01;
   todoExec():aTodo(_TYPE){};
   todoExec(std::string command):aTodo(_TYPE){_command=command;};
   void Do(){std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;};
   virtual ~todoExec(){};

   std::string getCommand(){return _command;};


};

class todoFactory{
private:

protected:


public:
   std::unique_ptr<aTodo> retrieveAtodo(const std::string & total){
   std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
   char type=total.at(0);
   std::cout << "bitset: " << std::bitset<8>(type) << std::endl;
   std::string remainder=total.substr(1);
   if(type==0x01){
      std::cout << "remainder in retrieve: " << remainder << std::endl;
      std::unique_ptr<todoExec> tmp(new todoExec());
      std::stringstream archive_stream(remainder);
      std::cout << "stream remainder: " << archive_stream.str() << std::endl;
   {     
      boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
      archive >> *tmp;
      }
      std::cout << "unserialized type: " << std::bitset<8>(tmp->getInitType()) << std::endl;
      std::cout << "unserialized command: " << tmp->getCommand() << std::endl;
      return std::move(tmp);
   }
   };

   std::unique_ptr<aTodo> createAtodo(char type,std::string command){

      if(type==0x01){
         std::unique_ptr<todoExec> tmp(new todoExec(command));
         return std::move(tmp);
      }
   };


};

int main(){
   char mtype=0x01;
   std::string dataToSend = "ls -al /home/ajonen";
   std::unique_ptr<todoFactory> tmpTodoFactory; //create factory
   std::unique_ptr<aTodo> anExecTodo=tmpTodoFactory->createAtodo(mtype,dataToSend); //create ExecTodo from factory
   if(auto* m = dynamic_cast<todoExec*>(anExecTodo.get()))
      std::cout << "command to serialize: " << m->getCommand() << std::endl;
   //archive
   std::string remainder = anExecTodo->oarchive();
   //now read in results that are sent back
   std::unique_ptr<aTodo> theResult;
   theResult=tmpTodoFactory->retrieveAtodo(remainder);
   std::cout << "resultant type: " << std::bitset<8>(theResult->getInitType()) <<std::endl;
   if(auto* d = dynamic_cast<todoExec*>(theResult.get()))
      std::cout << "resultant Command: " << d->getCommand() <<std::endl;


   return 0;
}
```

And here is the program output:

```
command to serialize: ls -al /home/ajonen
length: 36
here
bitset: 00000001
remainder in retrieve: 22 serialization::archive 12 0 0 1

stream remainder: 22 serialization::archive 12 0 0 1

serialize todoexec
unserialized type: 00000001
unserialized command: 
resultant type: 00000001
resultant Command:
```

I also found out that the serialize method is only being called for the base class aTodo.  I am going to need to find a way to make that virtual, but it is a template function.  That is problem number one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because all of the factory functions have missing returns.

Next up, using a type code in a class hierarchy is a [Design Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Concrete hints:

- serialize the same type as you deserialize
- let Boost Serialization handle the polymorphism (otherwise, why do you use polymorphism, or why do you use Boost Serialization?). Boost handles it when you serialize (smart) pointers to base.
- register your classes (BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT). You had included the header but didn't use it.
- <sub>There doesn't seem to be a reason for the factory. Consider dropping it</sub>

In general, remove cruft. it's hard to think when your code is too noisy. Here's my cleaned up version:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3adf446ce8fbe17)</kbd>**

This also uses Boost for streaming to string without unnecessary copying.

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/unique_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace Todo
{
    struct BaseTodo {
        using Ptr = std::unique_ptr<BaseTodo>;

        virtual ~BaseTodo() = default;
        virtual void Do() = 0;
        virtual unsigned getInitType() { return 0x00; };

      private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar &, unsigned) {}
    };

    class Exec : public BaseTodo {
      public:
        Exec(std::string const &command = "") : _command(command){};

        virtual unsigned getInitType() { return 0x01; };
        virtual void Do() { std::cout << "foo: " << getCommand() << std::endl; };

        std::string getCommand() const { return _command; };

      private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
            boost::serialization::base_object<BaseTodo>(*this);
            ar &_command;
        }

        std::string _command;
    };
}

//BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(BaseTodo)
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Todo::BaseTodo)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Todo::Exec)

namespace Todo 
{
    class Factory {
        Factory() = default;
      public:
        using Ptr = BaseTodo::Ptr;
        using FactoryPtr = std::shared_ptr<Factory>;

        static FactoryPtr create() { return FactoryPtr(new Factory); }

        static std::string save(Ptr todo) {
            std::string out;
            {
                namespace io = boost::iostreams;
                io::stream<io::back_insert_device<std::string> > os(out);

                boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(os);
                archive << todo;
            }

            return out;
        }

        static Ptr load(std::string const &s) {
            Ptr p;
            {
                namespace io = boost::iostreams;
                io::stream<io::array_source> is(io::array_source{ s.data(), s.size() });
                boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(is);
                archive >> p;
            }
            return std::move(p);
        }

        Ptr createExec(std::string command) { return BaseTodo::Ptr(new Exec(command)); }
    };
}

int main() {
    auto factory = Todo::Factory::create();

    // ROUNDTRIP save,load
    auto todo = factory->load(
            factory->save(
                factory->createExec("ls -al /home/ajonen")
            )
        );

    std::cout << "Type: " << std::hex << std::showbase << todo->getInitType() << std::endl;
    todo->Do();
}
```

Comment: Posted [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30211366/85371) without virtuals, inheritance and dynamic allocations

Comment: Thank you sehe.  I am going to debug through your example to see the best practices you lay out.

Comment: sehe.  What do you recommend for learning the visitor programming style as above.  Also what do you recommend to learn boost in general.  I have only been programming for a short time and boost is a bit of a jump for me.

Comment: Also what does this mean: "using a type code in a class hierarchy is a Design Smell."

Comment: It means that it is very very frequently a sign of a bad design. You can follow that link. The `typeid` is _supposed_ to "be" this type code, and virtual dispatch is _supposed_ to remove the need for branching. As you can see, I have a sample here that does _perfectly fine_ without the branching, and in the other answer where the typecode is the `variant`'s discriminator. So it doesn't really matter whether you prefer runtime polymorphism (here) or static polymorphism (the other answer), but whatever you do, don't do the work twice. It creates a mess and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @user249806 for learning c++  I can only recommend a long breath. Take your time. Only good tutoring/mentoring really helps, IMO. Otherwise it's just hacking your way through the jungle. And learning from your (frequent) bleeds

Comment: I really appreciate your tutoring/mentoring right now!  I am working on a project that uses sockets and client server programming.  I realize that this factory is overkill.  I am trying to learn some concepts at the same time.  I don't really even need boost for these basic objects as I could write a simple enough virtual serialize function and just call that.  I am definitely over complicating a simple program.

Comment: ahh i understand.  I am type coding my todoExec with 0x01 and that is bad.  Great advise.  Thanks for the excellent example.  Time to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another take without virtuals, inheritance and dynamic allocations:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbf3a0601480b2dd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/variant.hpp>

#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

namespace Todo
{
    struct None {
        void Do() const {};
        template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar&, unsigned) {}
    };

    class Exec {
      public:
        Exec(std::string const &command = "") : _command(command){};
        void Do() const { std::cout << "foo: " << getCommand() << std::endl; };

        std::string getCommand() const { return _command; };

      private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template <class Ar> void serialize(Ar &ar, unsigned) {
            ar &_command;
        }

        std::string _command;
    };

    using Todo = boost::variant<None, Exec>;

    struct Factory {
        static std::string save(Todo const& todo) {
            std::string out;
            {
                namespace io = boost::iostreams;
                io::stream<io::back_insert_device<std::string> > os(out);

                boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(os);
                archive << todo;
            }

            return out;
        }

        static Todo load(std::string const &s) {
            Todo todo;
            {
                namespace io = boost::iostreams;
                io::stream<io::array_source> is(io::array_source{ s.data(), s.size() });
                boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(is);
                archive >> todo;
            }
            return std::move(todo);
        }
    };
}

namespace visitors {
    namespace detail {
        template <typename F> struct internal_vis : boost::static_visitor<void> {
            internal_vis(F& f) : _f(f) {}
            template <typename... T>
                void operator()(T&&... a) const { return _f(std::forward<T>(a)...); }
            private:
                F& _f;
        };
    }

    template <typename F, typename V>
    void apply(F const& f, V const& v) { return boost::apply_visitor(detail::internal_vis<F const>(f), v); }

    template <typename F, typename V>
    void apply(F const& f, V& v) { return boost::apply_visitor(detail::internal_vis<F const>(f), v); }
}

namespace Todo { namespace Actions { template <typename T>
        void Do(T const& todo) {
            visitors::apply([](auto const& cmd) { cmd.Do(); }, todo);
        }
} }

int main() {
    using namespace Todo;
    Factory factory;

    // ROUNDTRIP save,load
    auto todo = factory.load(
            factory.save(
                Exec("ls -al /home/ajonen")
            )
        );

    std::cout << "Type: " << std::hex << std::showbase << todo.which() << std::endl;

    Actions::Do(todo);

}
```

Prints

```
Type: 0x1
foo: ls -al /home/ajonen
```